# Unable to edit in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Take a look at those two pictures in order to know what happens in my page only in Safari on MAC. So this doesn't happen even on Safari in Windows which is already odd.

[image]

[image]

This is the code that we are using.

```js
    $(".map-table-cx-edit").on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var cxId = $(this).attr("id").split("cx-edit-").join('');
        var cols = $(".map-table-col-"+cxId);
        cols.find('.map-table-displayfield').hide();
        cols.find('.map-table-editfield').show();
        Cockpit.loadMapTableHeight($("#map-table-clone"));
        Cockpit.Maptable.loadPhases();
        return false;
    });
```

```css
      div.tp-panel, div.map-table-displayfield, div.map-table-editfield {
        display: none;
      }
      span.map-table-displayfield {
        max-height: 68px !important;
      }
```

```html
<div data-id="64382" class="corner-ca" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<span class="map-table-displayfield" style="display: none;">DASFGAGasdffasdf</span>
  <span class="map-table-editfield" style="overflow: inherit; position: relative; display: inline-block;">
    <input name="data[CustomerAction][64382][title]" class="map-table-header-input" maxlength="140" value="DASFGAGasdffasdf" id="CustomerAction64382Title" required="required" type="text">
  </span>
</div>
```

If you need anymore information, let me know. I don't know where to look.

The specific problem occurs when man clicks on a form field then the save and cancel button are behind the form. This happens only in Safari. 
Also as added information, I can see the cursor, but I can't see the buttons (Cancel and Save).

Comment: Why are you running Safari for Windows? It was discontinued _four years ago_.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Kyle, but that's not the point of my post. The point is that this doesn't only work on Safari on MAC OS.

Comment: Well, considering the engines are totally different, I'm not surpised things work on one version and not another. But you also haven't outlined the specific problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right Kyle. Sorry for not making myself clear. I have edited the question. If you need anything else, let me know.